# Eclipse dosn't see JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

I had installed Eclipse and it was working well few days ago. Now I can't create Java project, there is no such option and in the Eclipse Preferences there is no mention about the word Java.
I was re-installing several times from Software Center and the result was same.

What should I do?
I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS. Can this happen because of system updates?

Comment: Type 'java -version' and 'javac -version' into a terminal. Do they both display a java version, or do they return an error?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_55" / 

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) / 

OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode) / 

javac 1.7.0_55

Comment: try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496755/eclipse-not-using-path/497290#497290)

Comment: Which Eclipse distribution do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse runs, you have an installed and working Java.

Check your Eclipse distribution, you should install <kbd>Eclipse IDE for Java Developers</kbd> or <kbd>Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers</kbd> from [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/).

EG:

[image]

---

Open the Preferences via

<kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

and navigate to

<kbd>Java</kbd> > <kbd>Installed JREs</kbd>

and you will see something like this

[image]

Press <kbd>Add</kbd> to configure more JREs

[image]