# Eclipse not using PATH

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse

I am facing an issue of Eclipse not picking up the VM from the PATH environment variable. I follow the below steps to reproduce the error:

1. Downloaded the appropriate version of Oracle's JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp
2. extracted it:

   ```
   tar zxvf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz ~/DEV
   ```
3. Added to `PATH`:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/faizal/DEV/jdk1.8.0_05
   export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
   ```
4. Confirmed `java` is available in PATH by restarting system and executing `java` in random folder in bash:

   ```
   cd ~
   java
   ```

But when I run Eclipse, I get the error :

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: /home/faizal/DEV/eclipse-luna/eclipse/jre/bin/java java in your current PATH
```

I can make it work only by creating a symbolic link `java` in `/bin` to point to `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. Why is Eclipse not working without this symbolic link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables):

> Shell config files such as ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, and
>   ~/.bash_login are often  suggested for setting environment variables.
>   While this may work on Bash shells for programs started from the
>   shell, variables set in those files are not available by default to
>   programs started from the graphical environment in a desktop session.

If you are running eclipse from your desktop session, you should modify your **~/.profile**.

> In this file you can also place environment variable assignments,
>   since it gets executed automatically by the DisplayManager during the
>   start-up process desktop session as well as by the login shell when
>   one logs in from the textual console.

Comment: For the benefit of others, in `~/.profile`, you cannot refer to environment variables created in `~/.bashrc`. So you will have to create them again in `~/.profile`, if required. Also, a system restart is required for the changes in `~/.profile` to be seen by Eclipse.