# Environment Variable - how does properly set them (bashrc or profile)

Tags: environment-variables, system-settings

I am very new in Ubuntu and I am lost about Environment Variable. I have read  some Forums but I didn't understand yet.

If I type `java -version` I got the java confirmation but if I type `echo $JAVA_HOME` there is nothing or `echo $PATH` there is nothing related to java.

In some forum I read to create `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` file and add the export commands. Other one tells to edit `/etc/environment`, other tells to add export commands in `/etc/profile` and even other one tells to edit `bash.bashrc`.

Currently, there is the java in my Ubuntu in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre` and I am able to run some java tools (eg. Eclipse) but I am trying to add Maven and I am very confused how do the environment variables work in Ubuntu. I came from Windows and basically I would like to set these variables as simple as possible.

Comment: One of the document mentioned in this link I have read (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). But I am still confused. For instance: I added Maven variables in /etc/profile and when I type mvn -v I see with other Maven information "Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre" but where is this JAVA_HOME settled in? It is strange for me because if I type echo $JAVA_HOME the outcome is blank. Do "apt get install" creates automatically some variables in certain file? If so, where is this file?

Comment: One more doubt: I didn't find ~/.pam_environment. I found etc/pam.conf. Are they the same?

Comment: 1. Probably `JAVA_HOME` isn't set. Maven takes it's location from `default.java` alternative. 2. Not the same. Everything in `/etc` is system-wide and `~/` is user-wide. I recommend you to place `JAVA_HOME` inside `/etc/environment` unless custom user java home is required.

Comment: Actually, most of the questions you have are answered in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables For instance it recommends that you don't edit `/etc/profile` directly. So `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` or (as @Danatela suggested) `/etc/environment` are proper places.

Comment: Take a look at this [Eclipse not using PATH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496755/eclipse-not-using-path/497290#497290)

Comment: Danatela, sorry for the simple question and not related to the origin question but what does ~/ mean? Does it point for the user home?

Comment: Gunnar, where is ~/.pam_environment mentioned in the article?

Comment: here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4ALw.pam_environment