# Having trouble to find the node in ubuntu 14.04 after installing

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I installed the NodeJS in Ubuntu 14.04 by `nvm` by following this site [Installing NodeJS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)
Though I had the following problem as

```
nvm ls
    sbin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/sbin/alias’: Permission denied
```

Then I found to resolve this as (from [NVM solution](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/433))

```
$ export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
$ echo $NVM_DIR
/home/roy/.nvm
```

Then It works fine.

Now the problem, I face is that if I restart or even open a new console, I can't find the `node` again.

```
roy@Croy:~$ node -version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:

 * node

 * nodejs-legacy

Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I have to follow those steps,

I do `nvm install 0.11.13` then it shows

```
v0.11.13 is already installed.
Now using node v0.11.13
```

Here is my  [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846550/having-trouble-to-find-the-node-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-installing) - the following answer is not working.

How to come out from here ?

Comment: try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496755/eclipse-not-using-path/497290#497290) File ~/.profile is used for both desktop session and for textual session.

Comment: Reading the guide that you've followed, it seems that `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.7.0/install.sh | sh` step went wrong. You can save your ~/.profile (make a copy in /tmp), redo this step and check what is new by `diff /tmp/.profile ~/.profile`

Answer (score 39):

As seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538996/executing-certain-commands-do-absolutely-nothing/544647#544647)

1. Run command:

   ```
   which node
   ```

   and in my case it displayed `/usr/sbin/node`.
2. If it says command not found, skip to 3. Remove it by

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/sbin/node
   ```
3. Run command:

   ```
   which nodejs
   ```

   In my case it displayed `/usr/bin/nodejs`
4. Make a link

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
   ```

   OR

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
   ```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Run command:

```
nodejs -v
```

For more information: See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-repo-nodejs-require-symlink-to-node-to-use-forever).

Answer (score 2):

As seen [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-repo-nodejs-require-symlink-to-node-to-use-forever)

> Because of a conflict with another package, the executable from the
>   Ubuntu repositories is called `nodejs` instead of node. Keep this in
>   mind as you are running software.

```
user@xxx:~ $ node --version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
* node
* nodejs-legacy
Ask your administrator to install one of them

user@xxx:~ $ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Node has a different name in the current version, mine is `v0.10.25`.

The current `node` is just `nodejs`.

To use the old commands you have to create a symbolic link like this.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

and that's it.

Run: `node --version`

Comment: Suggestion: Regarding "the current version", it is better to note which version did you mean i.e. `0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1` for trusty release?

Answer (score 0):

The following line adds node to your `$PATH`:

```
nvm alias default 5.1
```

Use your installed node version.

Answer (score 0):

**How about using the official instructions from the [nodejs site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)**:

For v6:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For v4:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I've tested these from Windows bash (via subsystem for Linux - 14.04) and it had the correct `node` alias. Running `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` without first running the setup script will result in you getting node 0.10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. But I stumbled upon this when I faced the same problem with NPM on WSL2.

I had to create a bash alias to point to the npm that I installed on ubuntu wsl.

```
alias npm=/usr/bin/npm
```