# executing certain commands do absolutely nothing

Tags: bash, npm

I have installed 3 new packages recently through NPM and none of them are executing.

I ran `sudo npm install -g ionic` and the installation looked like normal.

Then I can run `which ionic` and I get `/usr/local/bin/ionic` which looks good.

But if I run `ionic start myApp tabs` according to the documentation this should create a new ionic project. But instead it does absolutely nothing. No output on the command line, no project created. I press enter to execute the command and it **immediately** returns to another line on the command line as if I simply pressed enter with no command entered at all... This may not be clear, sorry.

I tried uninstalling ionic with `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic` which uninstalled it successfully, and then re-installed it. No change in behavior. Same is happening for the packages `cordova` and `bower`. Note: all of these I installed at the same time, and all of them are not working. No output, no errors, no nothing. Running them with `sudo` doesn't make a difference either.

I am running ubuntu 14.04.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Run

   ```
   which node
   ```

   and in my case it displayed `/usr/sbin/node`.
2. If it says `command not found`, skip to 3. Remove it by

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/sbin/node
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   which nodejs
   ```

   in my case it displayed `/usr/bin/nodejs`.
4. Make a link

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
   ```

   OR

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
   ```

Comment: Option 4A worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I re-installed my OS and therefore cordova. This literally saved my bum as even typing cordova did nothing. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow. Searched for ages and this was the only solution which worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it also can be because of outdated nodejs installed
according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362636/phonegap-cli-on-linux-doesnt-do-anything it can be fixed in next way:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
npm update npm -g
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n stable
```

and then `npm remove -g ionic && npm install -g ionic`

Answer (score -1):

I think installing any application other than apt-get may have the same problem.Try to use

```
which ionic start MyApps tab
```

Or

```
which ionic
```

Then

```
-command for importing templates here- start MyApps tab
```