# bash ./eclipse permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, wine, android, eclipse

I just downloaded the adt bundle.As per the instructions on the android site , it just says that double click on the eclipse icon and the IDE should start right away. But when I do so it searches for an application to run it . I even used wine to run it but it also failed. Now when i try to run it from the terminal , the following error pops up:

bash: ./eclipse: Permission denied

So , can anyone please help me out on this one?

Comment: Did you give the executable permission for eclipse binary file?

Comment: Tried doing that , but it is getting un-ticked automatically

Comment: I guess that are missing some environment variable. Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496755/eclipse-not-using-path) link, maybe it could be useful.

Comment: Actually got it to work. The error was solved by starting the adt bundle from the desktop i.e. pasting the extracted folder in desktop

Comment: But now there is a problem with the sdk manager

Comment: Please either post an answer explaining how you solved this or delete the question since nobody else will be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drive in which I had pasted the ADT bundle was formatted in NTFS format so for the file to work , I had to use it from the drive which was formatted in ext4 format i.e. the home directory